# How to convert from long to wide format when the column numbers per row are variable? (MATLAB)

Tags: performance, matlab, indexing, reshape

I have a time series dataset of accelerometry values where there are many sub-seconds of measurements but the actual number of sub-seconds recorded per second is variable.

So I would be starting with something that looks like this:

| Date time | Dec sec | Acc X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | .00 | 0.5 |
| 1 | .25 | 0.5 |
| 1 | .50 | 0.6 |
| 1 | .75 | 0.5 |
| 2 | .00 | 0.6 |
| 2 | .40 | 0.5 |
| 2 | .80 | 0.5 |
| 3 | .00 | 0.5 |
| 3 | .50 | 0.5 |
| 4 | .00 | 0.6 |
| 4 | .25 | 0.5 |
| 4 | .50 | 0.5 |
| 4 | .75 | 0.5 |

And trying to convert it to wide format where each row is a second, and the columns are the decimal seconds corresponding to each second.

| sub1 | sub2 | sub3 | sub4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .5 | .5 | .6 | .5 |
| .6 | .5 | .5 | NaN |
| .5 | .5 | NaN | NaN |
| .6 | .5 | .5 | .5 |

In code this would look like:

```
%Preallocate some space
Dpts_observations = NaN(13,3);

%These are the "seconds" number
Dpts_observations(:,1)=[1 1 1 1...
                        2 2 2...
                        3 3...
                        4 4 4 4];

%These are the "decimal seconds"
Dpts_observations(:,2) = [0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75...
                          0.00 0.33 0.66...
                          0.00 0.50 ...
                          0.00 0.25 0.50 0.75]

%Here's actual acceleration values
Dpts_observations(:,3) = [0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5...
                          0.6 0.5 0.5...
                          0.4 0.5...
                          0.5 0.5 0.6 0.4]

%I have this in a separate file but I have summary data that helps me
determine the row indexes corresponding to sub-seconds that belong to the same second and I use them to manually extract from long form to wide form.

%Create table to hold indexing information
Seconds = [1 2 3 4];
Obs_per_sec = [4 3 2 4];
Start_index = [1 5 8 10];
End_index = [4 7 9 13];
Dpts_attributes = table(Seconds, Obs_per_sec, Start_index, End_index);

%Preallocate new array
Acc_X = NaN(4,4);

%Loop through seconds
for i=1:max(size(Dpts_attributes))
   Acc_X(i, 1:Dpts_attributes.Obs_per_sec(i))=Dpts_observations(Dpts_attributes.Start_index(i):Dpts_attributes.End_index(i),3);
end
```

Now this is working but its very slow. In reality, I have a huge data set consisting of millions of seconds and I'm hoping there might be a better solution than the one I currently have going. My data is all numeric to try to make everything as fast a possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Is obtaining `Obs_per_sec` the hard part for you, or do you feel that the code is too slow as it is? Did you try this without using `table`? That’s a slow data type. You could directly use the data arrays instead of sticking them into a table and then indexing into them there.

Comment: No, the Obs_per_sec isn't a problem and I only use table for calling the indexes (just to keep track of the different variables). I try to stick to arrays as much as possible. It's the loop that's the slow part but because the number columns per row is variable I don't see a way around using it. I wish there was a way to reshape the data but I don't think you can use reshape if your # columns is variable.

Comment: Yeah, you cannot reshape. Loops are not inherently slow in MATLAB, they used to be back in the day, but that’s not true any more. But you need to remove custom function calls from inside the loop. Table indexing requires a function call, plain array indexing doesn’t. So do try to use a plain array. `Acc_X(i, 1:Obs_per_sec(i))` is much faster than `Acc_X(i, 1:Dpts_attributes.Obs_per_sec(i))`. If you really want to tidy up the code, use a struct, not a table.

Comment: Take a look at `unstack`